# getaddrinfo() function returns the wrong IP address

Tags: c, sockets, ip, ip-address, getaddrinfo

I am trying to resolve a URL's IP address using getaddrinfo(), but it always returns the wrong IP address, I have tried with several URL's and the result is same.  any help wold be greatly appreciated.

The program returnes the ip address : 209.85.175.99 insted of returning the real IP which is 74.125.39.147

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int
main()
{
 char *hostname = "www.google.lk";
 struct addrinfo hints, *res;
 struct in_addr addr;
 int err;

 memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
 hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
 hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

 if ((err = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
 printf("error %d\n", err);
 return 1;
 }

 addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(res->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;

 printf("ip address : %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));

 freeaddrinfo(res);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you behind some kind of proxy? or is there something wrong in your etc/hosts ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a wrong one?

>nslookup www.google.lk
Server:  dir-320
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.l.google.com
Addresses:  209.85.148.147
          209.85.148.99
          209.85.148.103
          209.85.148.104
          209.85.148.105
          209.85.148.106
Aliases:  www.google.lk
          www.google.com

Comment: Maybe you should try with a name that has a more straightofrward resolution than a Google server with multiple layers of aliasing and round-robin resolution.   How about `stackoverflow.com`?  (The resolution of Google server names even depends on the location from where you resolve them.)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I solved the problem, there was nothing wrong in the coding, the URL I was using was the problem, as Seven suggested stackoverflow.com is resolved correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Though i might add.....  getaddrinfo() returns a **list** of addresses.  Check out the man page for an example on how to iterate over the results.

Comment: use `-Wall`, some of the header files are missing..

Answer (score 6):

google.com can resolve to different IP addresses depending on your own location. It's kind of load balancing trick.